# Javascript / jQuery String Manipulation, wrap <b> tags around string of all text with a colon directly after

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var string = 'Item 1: Description of Item 1 | Item 2: Description of Item 2 | Item 3: description of item 3';
```

I want to manipulate the string to wrap b tags around the title and remove the `|` symbol. So that it becomes:

```
var fixedString = <b>Item 1:</b> Description of Item 1 <b>Item 2:</b> Description of item 2 <b>Item 3:</b> Description of Item 3
```

I tried some regular expressions but I don't think I did it right at all.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern needs to match:

1. The beginning of the string ***or*** a `|`
2. Any leading spaces
3. Non-colon characters
4. A colon

Characters from #3 & #4 should be put between `<b>` and `</b>`.

The regex translation would be to use

```
(?:^|\|)\s*([^:]*:)
```

And then use this as the replacement string:

```
<b>$1</b>
```

Here, `$1` refers to the characters that were inside the first capture group.

```js
var string = 'Item 1: Description of Item 1 | Item 2: Description of Item 2 | Item 3: description of item 3';
var fixedOutput = string.replace(/(?:^|\|)\s*([^:]*:)/g, '<b>$1</b>');
document.body.innerHTML = fixedOutput;
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC0xQ7/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex.

```
([^:]+)([^|]+\|?)
```

use negated character class with matches.

```
var string = 'Item 1: Description of Item 1 | Item 2: Description of Item 2 | Item 3: description of item 3';

var fixedString = string.replace(/([^:]+)([^|]+\|?)/g,"<b>$1</b>$2");
console.log(fixedString);
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW6bG4/1)